# How to quit from a catch exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm using java to connect to http server. All is fine. Of course I catch exceptions (`SocketTimeoutException`, `ConnectException`, `IOException`). But my problem is when (for example) an `ConnectException` occurs, the app stay stucked. I can't anymore continue in an other part of program... I tried `"return ..", System.exit` (but I don't want to exit from application). Any idea ?

The skeleton prog looks like this:

```
boolean metod_to_check_http_server(){

try{
Create_connection(URL);
Set_Time_Out(3000);
open_HTTP_Connection();
Close_Connection();
return true; // All this part is fine...
}


catch (EXCEPTIONS)
{ // Here I know I have connection problem
// how could I return to main prog from here ?
// return false ? not work...
// System.exit(..); // too violent !
// so ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add finally block to your try - catch statement you can continue  your flow

```
try
{

}
catch{

}
finally{

}
```

Comment: It's always the most basic things that stuck. I saw the "finally" block in doc, but didn't write it nice. Of course, it works. So thanks to all of you to remove the shadow on my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put finally block in you code after the catch one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question cannot be answered without knowing more about your program and environment, but it might be a good idea to inform the user about the connection failure, for example in a dialog saying "Connection failed". And don't forget to close any open connections in a `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

You should do exception handling yourself, and return a false if connection fails or is invalid....

```
boolean method_to_check_http_server(){

    try{
        Create_connection(URL);
        Set_Time_Out(3000);
        open_HTTP_Connection();
        return true; // All this part is fine...
    } catch (EXCEPTIONS) {
        displayError();
        return false;
    } finally {
        Close_Connection();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I made sure that my connection is closed (in the finally block) so that I don't leave opened sockets running in some OS thread somewhere.